# Установить основное окно процесса выше чем окно в полноэкранном режиме

Tags: c#, winapi, dll

В user32dll есть функция, которая позволяет устанавливать процесс выше остальных

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

но если открыть какое-либо окно в полноэкранном режиме, то процесс все равно сворачивается. Есть ли возможность, чтобы оно даже над полноэкранными висело, или же этой привилегией обладает только диспетчер задач?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду полноэкранный режим DirectX, например у 3D игры? Если так, что данная функция не поможет решить эту проблему. А поможет только DirectX Overlay, и процесс это [не тривиальный](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1683524/12888024). Как альтернативу, можно играть не в полноэкранном режиме, а в окне, развернутом на весь экран, большинство популярных игр поддерживают "режим полноэкранного окна" без рамок.